# Get points which are within a given distance in two different matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices `A` and `B`, in which the number of rows can vary. `A` and `B` do not necessarily have the same number of rows.

For example:

```
A = [ 110    90
      130   140
      230    50
      370   210 ];
B = [ 321    95
      102    35
      303   200 ];
```

Now matrix `A` and `B` have 'corresponding points'. Corresponding points are rows where the values in the 2nd column of both matrices are within `+/-20`.

For example:

- `A(1,2) = 90` and `B(1,2) = 95`, the difference is within `+/-20` so `A(1,:)` and `B(1,:)` are corresponding points.
- `A(2,2) = 140` and `B(2,2) = 35`, the difference is **not** within `+/-20` so `A(2,:)` and `B(2,:)` are **not** corresponding points.
- `A(3,2) = 50` and `B(2,2) = 35`, the difference is within `+/-20` so `A(3,:)` and `B(2,:)` are corresponding points.

Using this I want to store the corresponding points of `A` and `B` in `C` and `D` respectively. For the above example, the final matrices should look like this:

```
C = [ 110    90
      230    50
      370   210 ]
D = [ 321    95
      102    35
      303   200 ]
```

Comment: What's the significance of them being in different columns? If you're just after one-dimensional points that are near each other, throw them in an array, sort it, walk through while checking the differences.

Comment: @Carlos But then you could get that two points, both within `A` or both within `B`, are 'corresponding points' with each other. This would be wrong according to how the problem is defined.

Comment: Ah I see now. I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the distances using `pdist2`

```
dists = pdist2( A(:,2), B(:,2) )
>> dists = [  5    55   110
             45   105    60
             45    15   150
            115   175    10 ]
```

Then get the indices of all 'corresponding points', as defined by a threshold of 20.

```
% Get combinations within tolerance
idx = dists < 20;
% Get indices  
[iA, iB] = find(idx);
```

Then you can create the final matrices

```
C = A(iA, :);
D = B(iB, :);
```

### ---

**Edit:** One way to ensure each pairing is unique (i.e. `A(1,:)` cannot be paired with multiple rows from `B`) would be to get the minimum `dists` for each row/column. Note: this would still give you duplicate matches if the distances are exactly the same, you haven't defined how this should be handled.

```
dists = pdist2( A(:,2), B(:,2) );
% Set values which are greater than the row/column minima to be infinity.
% This means they will never be within the tolerance of 20 (or whatever else)
dists ( bsxfun(@gt, dists, min(dists,[],1)) | bsxfun(@gt, dists, min(dists,[],2)) ) = Inf;
% In MATLAB versions > 2016b, you can use implicit expansion to replace bsxfun
% That would be: dists( dists > min(dists,[],1) | dists > min(dists,[],2) )

% Now continue as before
[iA, iB] = find( dists < 20 );
C = A(iA, :);
D = B(iB, :);
```

Comment: Good. I don't know which one is better, but you can replace `pdist2` with `abs(B(:,2).'-A(:,2))`

Comment: @Adiel Note: you cannot do that in MATLAB pre-R2016b, when implicit expansion was introduced. You would have to do `abs(bsxfun( @minus, B(:,2).', A(:,2) ))` if you needed compatability. At that point, I'd say `pdist2` is just simpler! You can use `edit pdist2` and look at line 370 (in 2015b) to see how the distance is calculated using that method if you were interested (it's basically the same, difference squared square-rooted).

Comment: Hello @Wolfie, when I used matrices A = [354,63; 541,310; 354,63; 354,63]; B = [183,301; 408,302; 541,310]; I got iA =[2,2,2] which in my case not true becuase I have maximum one corresponding point within matrices. How to avoid this?